# unable to view shared folder in OneDrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am fairly new to SharePoint. I have used the following command in PnP Powershell to add permission to share a specific folder (Archives) to only allow a specific user (user1) to access the folder.

`Set-PnPFolderPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity "Documents/Archives/user1" -User user1@example.com -AddRole 'Contribute'`

After which, i went to user1 web OneDrive for Business and went to the Shared section. I am unable to find the shared folder. Am i doing it wrongly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the Powershell command you used just gave user1 the **Contribute permission level** for this folder. This does not mean that this folder will appear on the user1 web OneDrive for Business.

[image]

[image]

[image]

========================== **Updated Answer** ========================

**Please following steps:**

1.Ensure that the user has at least **Read permission level**

[image]

[image]

2.Access the Document library as this user

3.Select the folder and click "**Add shortcut to OneDrive**"

[image]

4.Go to the **user's OneDrive for Business page**, you will see this folder

[image]

Comment: would you be able to point me to the right direction on how can i make it appear on user1 web OneDrive for business? thank you.

Comment: Hi raymond. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!